# JObject.ToBsonDocument dropping values

Tags: json.net, mlab

I'm inserting raw JSON into a collection and finding that what is stored in the database is missing the values. For example, my collection is a collection of `BsonDocuments`:

```
_products = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("products");
```

The code to insert the JSON into the collection:

```
public int AddProductDetails(JObject json)
{
    var doc = json.ToBsonDocument(DictionarySerializationOptions.Document);
    _products.Insert(doc);
}
```

The JSON that is passed in looks like this:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Tags": [
    "book",
    "database"
  ],
  "Name": "Book Name",
  "Price": 12.12
}
```

But, what is persisted in the collection is just the properties with no values.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5165c7e10fdb8c09f446d720"
  },
  "Id": [],
  "Tags": [
    [],
    []
  ],
  "Name": [],
  "Price": []
}
```

Why are the values being dropped?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This does what I was expecting.

```
    public int AddProductDetails(JObject json)
    {
        BsonDocument doc = BsonDocument.Parse(json.ToString());
        _products.Insert(doc);
    }
```

Comment: You should mark this as the answer (even though it's your own), as it seems to have solved my issue too. Thanks!

Comment: Great! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: This is good but is there a more efficient version [3 years on]?  copying to String might be an 'expensive' operation for large JSON?

Comment: @JamesWoodall - 5 years now :-) you can check out my answer

Comment: @JamesWoodall you can use the `Newtonsoft.Json.Bson` nuget package to achieve this without serializing to/from a string. See my answer for an implementation of the mongo IBsonSerializer that uses this.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this issue when I had a C# class with a property of type `JObject`.

My Solution was to create `JObjectSerializer` for MondoDB and add the attribute to the property so Mongo serializer uses it. I assume if I tried hard enough I could register the below serializer in Mongo as the global one for this type as well.

Register serializer for property processing:

```
[BsonSerializer(typeof(JObjectSerializer))]
public JObject AdditionalData { get; set; }
```

The serializer itself:

```
public class JObjectSerializer : SerializerBase<JObject> // IBsonSerializer<JObject>
{
    public override JObject Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var myBSONDoc = BsonDocumentSerializer.Instance.Deserialize(context);
        return JObject.Parse(myBSONDoc.ToString());
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, JObject value)
    {
        var myBSONDoc = MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument.Parse(value.ToString());
        BsonDocumentSerializer.Instance.Serialize(context, myBSONDoc);
    }
}
```

Comment: `BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new JObjectSerializer());` is what you're looking for. Just stick it somewhere near your application startup and you won't need the property annotations.

Comment: Thank you! This did almost exactly what I needed. I had to tweak it slightly to handle null values correctly, but otherwise this is great! I added my updated version as an additional answer below.

Comment: I..... searched..... alll..... day...... for this..... I read the docs, then I read them again. Then I read the github. Then I scoured the internet. Then I scoured stackoverflow. Then I did all of those things again 3 more times.  sir... I think you sincerely. :)

Comment: You can use the `Newtonsoft.Json.Bson` package to avoid serializing to/from a string. See my answer below for JObjectSerializer that uses this.

Answer (score 8):

The problem when using `JObject.ToString`, `BsonDocument.Parse`, etc. is the performance is not very good because you do the same operations multiple times, you do string allocations, parsing, etc.

So, I have written a function that converts a `JObject` to an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` (only using enumerations), which is a type usable by one of the `BsonDocument` constructors. Here is the code:

```
public static BsonDocument ToBsonDocument(this JObject jo)
{
    if (jo == null)
        return null;

    return new BsonDocument(ToEnumerableWithObjects(jo));
}

public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> ToEnumerableWithObjects(this JObject jo)
{
    if (jo == null)
        return Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

    return new JObjectWrapper(jo);
}

private class JObjectWrapper : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
{
    private JObject _jo;

    public JObjectWrapper(JObject jo)
    {
        _jo = jo;
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetEnumerator() => new JObjectWrapperEnumerator(_jo);
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    public static object ToValue(JToken token)
    {
        object value;
        switch (token.Type)
        {
            case JTokenType.Object:
                value = new JObjectWrapper((JObject)token);
                break;

            case JTokenType.Array:
                value = new JArrayWrapper((JArray)token);
                break;

            default:
                if (token is JValue jv)
                {
                    value = ((JValue)token).Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    value = token.ToString();
                }
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }
}

private class JArrayWrapper : IEnumerable
{
    private JArray _ja;

    public JArrayWrapper(JArray ja)
    {
        _ja = ja;
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => new JArrayWrapperEnumerator(_ja);
}

private class JArrayWrapperEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    private IEnumerator<JToken> _enum;

    public JArrayWrapperEnumerator(JArray ja)
    {
        _enum = ja.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public object Current => JObjectWrapper.ToValue(_enum.Current);
    public bool MoveNext() => _enum.MoveNext();
    public void Reset() => _enum.Reset();
}

private class JObjectWrapperEnumerator : IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
{
    private IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>> _enum;

    public JObjectWrapperEnumerator(JObject jo)
    {
        _enum = jo.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public KeyValuePair<string, object> Current => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(_enum.Current.Key, JObjectWrapper.ToValue(_enum.Current.Value));
    public bool MoveNext() => _enum.MoveNext();
    public void Dispose() => _enum.Dispose();
    public void Reset() => _enum.Reset();
    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;
}
```

Comment: By far the most performant answer. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the BsonSerializer?

```
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
[...]
var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json);
```

BsonSerializer works with strings, so if the JSON argument is a JObject(or JArray, JRaw etc) you have to serialize it with JsonConvert.SerializeObject()

Comment: That doesn't compile.  This does, but generates the same results.var doc = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json.ToBsonDocument());

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument'

Comment: Sorry, my fault, BsonSerializer works with json strings, so before deserializing it you have to serialize it with JsonConvert.SerializeObject(), then you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of Andrew DeVries's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43707229/3746036) that includes handling for serializing/deserializing null values.

```cs
public class JObjectSerializer : SerializerBase<JObject>
{
    public override JObject Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        if (context.Reader.CurrentBsonType != BsonType.Null)
        {
            var myBSONDoc = BsonDocumentSerializer.Instance.Deserialize(context);
            return JObject.Parse(myBSONDoc.ToStrictJson());
        }
        else
        {
            context.Reader.ReadNull();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, JObject value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var myBSONDoc = BsonDocument.Parse(value.ToString());
            BsonDocumentSerializer.Instance.Serialize(context, myBSONDoc);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Writer.WriteNull();
        }
    }
}
```

The `ToStrictJson()` call is an extension method that wraps the call to the built-in BSON `ToJson()` method to include setting the output mode to strict. If this is not done, the parsing will fail because BSON type constructors will remain in the JSON output (`ObjectId()`, for example).

Here is the implementation of `ToStrictJson()` as well:

```cs
public static class MongoExtensionMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a JsonWriterSettings object to use when serializing BSON docs to JSON.
    /// This will force the serializer to create valid ("strict") JSON.
    /// Without this, Object IDs and Dates are ouput as {"_id": ObjectId(ds8f7s9d87f89sd9f8d9f7sd9f9s8d)}
    ///  and {"date": ISODate("2020-04-14 14:30:00:000")} respectively, which is not valid JSON
    /// </summary>
    private static JsonWriterSettings jsonWriterSettings = new JsonWriterSettings()
    {
        OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Custom extension method to convert MongoDB objects to JSON using the OutputMode = Strict setting.
    /// This ensure that the resulting string is valid JSON.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TNominalType">The type of object to convert to JSON</typeparam>
    /// <param name="obj">The object to conver to JSON</param>
    /// <returns>A strict JSON string representation of obj.</returns>
    public static string ToStrictJson<TNominalType>(this TNominalType obj)
    {
        return BsonExtensionMethods.ToJson<TNominalType>(obj, jsonWriterSettings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following. It's based on [Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52448766/7818969), thanks for the idea, and works in the same way, avoiding unnecessary serialization / deserialization into string.

It's just a bit more compact, thanks to Linq and C# 10:

```cs
public static BsonDocument ToBsonDocument(this JObject o) =>
    new(o.Properties().Select(p => new BsonElement(p.Name, p.Value.ToBsonValue())));

public static BsonValue ToBsonValue(this JToken t) =>
    t switch
    {
        JObject o => o.ToBsonDocument(),
        JArray a => new BsonArray(a.Select(ToBsonValue)),
        JValue v => BsonValue.Create(v.Value),
        _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"ToBsonValue: {t}")
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here involve serializing to and then deserializing from a string. Here is a solution that serializes to/from raw BSON instead. It requires the `Newtonsoft.Json.Bson` nuget package.

```
using System.IO;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Bson;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Zonal.EventPublisher.Worker
{
    public class JObjectSerializer : SerializerBase<JObject>
    {
        public override JObject Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        {
            using (var stream = new MongoDB.Bson.IO.ByteBufferStream(context.Reader.ReadRawBsonDocument()))
            using (JsonReader reader = new BsonDataReader(stream))
            {
                return JObject.Load(reader);
            }
        }

        public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, JObject value)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            using (JsonWriter writer = new BsonDataWriter(stream))
            {
                value.WriteTo(writer);

                var buffer = new MongoDB.Bson.IO.ByteArrayBuffer(stream.ToArray());
                context.Writer.WriteRawBsonDocument(buffer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register the serializer with:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new JObjectSerializer());
```

After that you can convert your JObject to a BsonDocument by using the `MongoDB.Bson.BsonExtensionMethods.ToBsonDocument` extension method:

```
var myBsonDocument = myJObject.ToBsonDocument()
```

And convert a BsonDocument back to a JObject by using the `MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer` class:

```
var myJObject = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<JObject>(myBsonDocument);
```